# Why is mercurial version always 1.3.1 even though I installed 1.6.4?

Tags: python, macos, mercurial

I ran `pip uninstall mercurial` Mac OSX 10.6.6, with and without `sudo`, in my virtualenv, and removed every trace of hg or mercurial on my machine. I tried re-installing like so:

- pip install mercurial==1.6.4
- http://mercurial.berkwood.com/ where I downloaded a Mac-specific version of 1.6.4

All efforts yielded the same from `hg --version`:

> Mercurial Distributed SCM (version
>   1.3.1)
>
> Copyright (C) 2005-2009 Matt Mackall
>    and others This is
>   free software; see the source for
>   copying conditions. There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY
>   or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Is this a bug? Shouldn't it display 1.6.4 instead of 1.3.1? If not, why?

Comment: Do a `which hg` on console, possibly the old one is in `/usr/bin` and the new one is in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I already did that. In fact, I removed *every* trace of hg on my entire system: `sudo find /. -name hg -delete` or made sure there were no remnants. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What does `which hg` says? and look where `pip` installs the `hg` binary.

Comment: @ İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez: ~/Sites/virtualenvs/metametrics/bin/hg

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez: Thank you for all of your questions. @jamessan helped me find the answer I needed below. Best wish :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hg binary is just a thin wrapper around the mercurial Python module.  It sounds like all you did was remove the old hg binary but not the old mercurial Python module, so the new install is picking up the old modules.

You can see where the modules are installed with `python -c 'import mercurial; print mercurial.__file__'`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. When I get time to do a fresh install of snow leopard, I'm going to be sure to always work in virtualenv.